# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' when reading a JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
I am trying to check a directory and list all of its folders and files. In case there is a folder, I want to list all the files within this folder( they are all in JSON format), then, I want to open each of these JSON files and perform a function on them.  But I get the following error and it seems that it is related to JSON, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
from os import listdir
import glob
import json
list_dir=[]
all_files=[]
read_file=[]

for r,d,f in os.walk(r'C:\aschemas-master'):  #show only directories along with path
   for dirs in d:
     filepath = os.path.join(r, dirs)
     list_dir.append(filepath)
for folders in list_dir:       
    all_files=os.listdir(folders)  
    for each_file in all_files:
        file_read=os.path.join(folders+'\\'+each_file)
        x=open(file_read)
        file_write=os.path.join(folders+'\\'+each_file+"_madh"+".txt")
        w=open(''.join(file_write),'w')
        **json_load=json.load(x.read())**
        for x in get_dotted_form("", json_load):  # calls the function
            w.write(x)
            w.write('\n')
        w.close()
```

Comment: That line of code is not in the code posted... also please post the whole error.

Comment: @AChampion, please look at **json_load=json.load(x.read())** in the code. Also, the whole error was posted.

Comment: Also, please only post the code relevant to the actual problem you have ... most of this code is irrelevant

Comment: @RushabhMehta, done!

Comment: You haven't posted the whole error, you would have a traceback which shows the line number and code that is causing the error. `return loads(fp.read(),...` is not in the code above so presumable the error includes additional details. However, you are using `load()` so you just need to pass in `x`, e.g. `json.load(x)`. The error line you did post implies that internally `json.load(x)` just call `json.loads(x.read())`, so what you currently have is `json.loads(x.read().read())` which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @AChampion, File "C:/UComplete_mapping.py", line 55, in <module>
    json_load=json.load(x.read())

Comment: @AChampion, when removing read, get this error again at the same line: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Good luck tracking down that error, it likely means you have a file without valid `json` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to @AChampion. I had some txt files in one of my folders!